# Rivermead Behavioral Memory Test- item 19- Belongings Delayed Recall scoring

Tags: memory

OT student here scoring the RBMT and for the Belongings Delayed recall section the manual does not describe a common situation I have encountered:

The client requires prompting to recall there are two belongings they must retrieve at the end of the assessment which are in 2 different locations. They must correctly say which belongings are in which location. Often times, the client will be prompted to remember the belongings (which automatically deducts two points), then, they correctly identify the belongings (for example a phone and a wallet) as well as the locations they are in (a desk drawer and a cabinet), except the client reverses the locations. For example, in reality, the phone is in the desk and the wallet in the cabinet but they falsely say the opposite: the phone is in the cabinet and the wallet in the desk.

As the client technically correctly identified the locations but got the placement of their belongings reversed, how would one score this? Is it a flat out zero or would they get 1 point for the locations because the belongings are reversed? Or would they get full marks since the locations are correctly identified?

Thanks!